# Writing json data into file using curl

Tags: php, json, file, curl

I am trying to store json data from the url into one file.I am getting error as

"Unable to save JSON to “result.txt”."
I have written following code,please help me

```
<?php

$outfile= 'result.txt';

$url='http://192.178.1.5:8888/GetUsers';

$rCURL = curl_init();

curl_setopt($rCURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($rCURL, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($rCURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$aData = curl_exec($rCURL);

curl_close($rCURL);

$result = json_decode ( $aData );
if($result) { 
    if(file_put_contents($outfile, $result, FILE_APPEND)) {
      echo "Saved JSON fetched from “{$url}” as “{$outfile}”.";
    }
    else {
      echo "Unable to save JSON to “{$outfile}”.";
    }
}
else {
   echo "Unable to fetch JSON from “{$url}”.";
}


?>
```

Comment: Is the file writable? Give it chmod perm 755 I think

Comment: check your php error log to trace error.

Comment: your're passing an object to `file_put_contents`. That's not allowed. It doesn't raise any error but the function returns `false`. See my answer for more details...

Answer (score 0):

Save the data without `json_decode`. Though http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php says data can be array, it gave me error working with array, instead save the data as string.

Comment: Saving data without json_decode is showing that "Saved JSON fetched from “http://192.178.1.5:8888/GetUsers” as “result.txt”." but in result.txt file i am getting
 {
  "Error": "Method not allowed"
}   
why this ??

Comment: that's what came back from your curl response. your file is working fine, now you have to make sure your curl call is right.

Comment: `curl_setopt($rCURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [ 'Accept: application/json', 'Content-Type: application/json']);` try setting this option after `CURLOPT_HEADER`

Comment: I tried this but still getting same thing in output file.

Comment: Does your url working correctly? Try browsing the url directly from browser and debug. I think the problem is on the url.

Comment: Can you share the codes of the url, where the call is going?

Comment: My url is perfectly working.It is showing proper result in postman.

Comment: Is the url expecting a GET request?

Comment: 405 is the http method not allowed status code. so its definitely something the api is expecting, but you are not providing. try removing `CURLOPT_HEADER` option | adding `curl_setopt($rCURL, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');` | send User-Agent in your request | If the api needs any authorization then you need to send cookies with header data | try boolean instead of integer values in curl options. Keep trying these. If still does not work, then sorry man. its beyond my reach.

Comment: try requesting the curl directly from your terminal, see what happens and play around with it. Hope the solution will appear soon.

Comment: Thanks for you help :) but problem still persist.If you know any other way in which i can store json data into file from url,please let me know.

Comment: try directly getting the json `file_get_contents('http://192.178.1.5:8888/GetUsers')`, `var_dump` this to see what's coming. For this to work, `file_get_contents` requires that `allow_url_fopen` is enabled. This can be done at runtime by including: `ini_set("allow_url_fopen", 1);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, use **[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)**. it will pen the file to get existing content

```
$result = json_decode ( $aData );
$current = file_get_contents($outfile);
if($result) { 
    if(file_put_contents($outfile, $result)) {
      echo "Saved JSON fetched from {$url} as {$outfile}.";
    }
    else {
      echo "Unable to save JSON to {$outfile}.";
    }
}
else {
   echo "Unable to fetch JSON from {$url}.";
}
```

Comment: Not working in my case.Showing Unable to save JSON to "result.txt" only.

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to your code you have to check is your file writable:

```
if (!is_writable($outfile)) {
    throw new \RuntimeException("$outfile is not writable.");
}
```

You should put this code before `file_put_contents`.

Answer (score 0):

I see some major issues with your code:

```
$result = json_decode ( $aData );
```

assuming `$aData` contains valid a JSON object `$result` will be an **object**.

You can't pass an **object** to `file_put_contents` as this function accepts only a string (or a single dimensional array).

If you try to do that the function will return `false`.

Assuming you're retrieving JSON data with the curl call I don't see the point of decoding it into an object. Just write the string from **curl** `$aData` to file.

Unless, of course, you have to do some data manipulation.

In that case mangle the data but, at the end, you have to produce a string before writing to file.

---

Assuming you fix the above issue, let `$result` be a string.

You have:

```
if( file_put_contents( $outfile, $result, FILE_APPEND ) )
```

As the function returns the number of bytes written and assuming `$result` may be an empty string the `if` clause should be rewritten as...

```
if( file_put_contents( $outfile, $result, FILE_APPEND ) !== false )
```

...in order to enter the "*operation succeeded*" code block if you write an empty string to the file.

---

As last note, of course, the file must be writeable.

---

**EDIT**

I read in the comments that the response from `curl` is

```
{ "Error": "Method not allowed" }
```

This is because you're not doing the `curl` call as the target server expects.

`Method not allowed` means that, for example, you're making a `GET` request while the server expects a `POST` for that endpoint.